# I can't get a return from my Button - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, message, messagebox

I'm pretty new to Tkinter and I'm trying to get a return from my button in messagebox using command=function but nothing seems to happen:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def start_game(dif):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    answer = messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?")
    if answer == True:
        root.deiconify()
        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a dificulty: ')

        def easy_difficulty():
            return dif + 1
            root.destroy()
        def hard_difficulty():
            return dif + 10
            root.destroy()

        easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy', command=easy_difficulty)
        hard_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Hard', command=hard_difficulty)
        
        mainLabel.pack()
        easy_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        hard_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

difficulty = start_game(0)
print(difficulty)
```

Comment: When you say "I'm trying to get a return from my button", what exactly do you mean? I can see that you are returning things from your `easy_difficulty` and `hard_difficulty` functions, but where do you expect these values to end up? Also, the calls to `root.destroy()` in either of those functions will never be executed, since you are returning from the functions on the line above each time respectively.

Comment: @Paul M. so how would get a `dif` to increase if I can't just return it in a function, do I increase it inside of `tk.Button()`?

Comment: Event-based programming just fundamentally works differently. If you want to get information out of a button callback, the normal way is to update some object or global state. It's also a bad idea to try to do anything "after" the `.mainloop` is entered; you're meant to have the entire lifetime of the GUI application in there.

Comment: I would recommend that you try to follow along with a tkinter tutorial before trying to implement your own stuff. For example, there is http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ .

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I read through the docs but I still don't have a solution, which part of the docs should I look through?

Comment: The point is that you need to reshape how you approach the program entirely to do GUI work; there aren't straightforward answers for questions like this, because the questions aren't well conceived.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is nowhere to return `dif+1` nor `dif+10`

If what you need is that value, 1 or 10, what I would suggest is to create a global variable, lets call it Dif.

```
Dif = 0
```

and in the easy or hard difficulty function instead of `return dif + 1 or 10` you need to fistable call the variable in the following way:

```
global Dif
```

and then:

```
Dif = dif+1       # or 10 if its int the hard function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return value in `easy_difficulty()` and `hard_difficulty()`. Just update the passed argument `dif` and return `dif` after `root.mainloop()`.  However you need declare `dif` as `nonlocal` inside `easy_difficulty()` and `hard_difficulty()`, otherwise it is treated as local variable:

Below is a modified code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def start_game(dif):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    answer = messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?")
    if answer == True:
        root.deiconify()
        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a dificulty: ')

        def easy_difficulty():
            nonlocal dif
            dif += 1
            root.destroy()

        def hard_difficulty():
            nonlocal dif
            dif += 10
            root.destroy()

        easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy', command=easy_difficulty)
        hard_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Hard', command=hard_difficulty)
        
        mainLabel.pack()
        easy_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        hard_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        root.mainloop()
    else:
        root.destroy()
    # return the updated 'dif'
    return dif

difficulty = start_game(0)
print(difficulty)
```